# Django: Get currently logged in user, not user from request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an external app - on another server and outside of Django project - calling list API view in my Django app and I need to limit the output of the API only to data owned by currently logged in user.

So I cannot user `request.user`, because the `request` is coming from outside and the user will always be `AnonymousUser`.

Instead, I would need to get the user that is currently logged in my Django app. How do I do that?

Comment: Probably you did not enable REST authentication: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: You mean your athentication backend is seperated from this django project?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How is "the user that is currently logged in" different from `request.user`?

Comment: Authentication is on Django backend side, and it is an external Bokeh app that is making the request. Hence request.user is anonymous, and instead I would like the Bokeh app to somehow ask Django app which user is currently logged in.

Comment: But there is no such thing as *the* user who is "currently" logged in. There may be many authenticated users, but each one is only "logged in" while they are actually making a request.